# NTC sensor in a Wheatstone bridge

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, thermistor, non-linear, graph

[image]

I put an NTC sensor into a Wheatstone bridge so it gave me a totally non linear curve (positive and negative). How can I make it linear to read it by a microcontroller?

Thanks.

Comment: Some simulation of NTC thermistor might allow you to fit a curve: https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/ntcthermistor.html?lcid=en-us&md5=016606ad63d142245d4a682017d4890b

Comment: Ditch the NTC and use a PTAT instead. There’s quite a number of three pin active sensors available from the big suppliers.

Comment: This can help ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/VazHi.png or this https://i.stack.imgur.com/riQCA.png

Answer (score 1):

There are many choices/tradeoffs to making a linear wide range (140'C) thermal sensor.

First and foremost decide on your budget and tolerance error.  The tradeoffs include 1kB memory for Look Up Table (LUT) , CPU cycles to compute log or 3rd or 5th order corrections, linearity, pin count with digital sensors, simplicity vs complexity, calibration costs , advanced methods to compute nonlinear error correction, rapid 2 temp tests to estimate the 3rd order equation or a simply a calibrated linear galvo scale.

So what is your temp. error budget and cost budget for NRE (time) and production cost?

Then choose analog or digital then choose from the many existing linear sensors or roll your own.

Further details you may find on the web such as this...  https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa12/snoaa12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An NTC *is* a nonlinear device.

Linearizing it in analog electronics is very hard, because the things you could use to linearize it depend on temperature, so that your measurement gets worse.

However, a microcontroller can very well apply a formula that converts a read value into temperature in nonlinear ways.

Solution: Don't linearize the reading, apply the linearization in the microcontroller, where it's

1. free
2. easy
3. independent of undesired temperature effect.

Comment: I want to generate 4-20 ma output , so I have no solution except making the sensor response linear

Comment: This still doesn't explain why it needs to be linear, reprogram the microcontroller to handle a curved response.

Comment: yeah, your sensor being nonlinear is something your processing system needs to linearize, not the sensor itself, @AbdereZake.